# how to add elements into a form by using ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form that has 4 fields

```
<form name="form">
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="edit.name"><br />
     age:
    <input type="text" ng-model="edit.age"><br />
     phone:
    <input type="text" ng-model="edit.phone"><br />
     address:
    <input type="text" ng-model="edit.address"><br />

  </form>
```

And i have an array in the app.js

```
 $scope.statuses = [
    {value: 1, text: 'status1'},
    {value: 2, text: 'status2'},
    {value: 3, text: 'status3'},
    {value: 4, text: 'status4'}
  ];
```

I am repeating that array in the html and what i want to do is that i want the text to appear in the form when a button such as "edit" is clicked
[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/VT1VSPsl7sbjuq3pOb3y?p=preview)

So basically as you can see in the plunker when i click on the edit button i want "status1" "status2" "status3" "status4" to appear in the fields that are in the form "name" "age" "phone" and "address"

Comment: Your question is unclear. State what exactly you want. Data to populate should come from etc.

Comment: What "text to appear", where in the form, what/where is this "edit" button?... too many questions

Comment: Just have a look at the plunker i have a edit button when i click the edit button
In the first field in the form that is "name" i should get "status1" and in the second field that is "age" i should get "status2" and so on.. is there a way in angularjs that we can do this? 
sorry for the question being unclear i am pretty new to all the programming thing

Comment: @GandharvGarg see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was a bit unclear, but I think what you want to do is change *statuses* to the form values.
I create this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bp2OWxGMrmdpOPYqWtEy?p=preview) for you

on your ng-click function. I change the *statuses* array text (which is shown with ng-repeat in your html) to your forms *edit* values:

```
$scope.editFunction = function(edit){
   $scope.statuses[0].text=edit.name;
   $scope.statuses[1].text=edit.age;
   $scope.statuses[2].text=edit.phone;
   $scope.statuses[3].text=edit.address;
};
```

or if you want your array values be in your form just reverse the = in your function like [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xfc7wO7TWfduQd4yYDmN) :
but in this case,if you want your empty form to work, you should declare edit before in your controller.

```
$scope.edit=[];

$scope.editFunction = function(edit){
   edit.name=$scope.statuses[0].text;
   edit.age=$scope.statuses[1].text;
   edit.phone=$scope.statuses[2].text;
   edit.address=$scope.statuses[3].text;
};
```

and so you are using ng-model.there is no need to pass argument to your function, you can use $scope.edit instead of a passing argument in your *editFunction*

Comment: No, What i wanted is that the status1 to appear in the text area in the name field and similarly status 2 in the age field by just a click of the edit button.

Sorry(I am noob ) for the question to be unclear i ll try to be more expressive next time

Comment: @GandharvGarg now I know what you want, see my updated answer ;)

Comment: Wow .. thanks a lot was struggling with this .. Thank you for your time and yes this was what i wanted ..

Comment: @GandharvGarg I just start learning angularjs myself and I know sometimes it get out of hand and you don't know what to do. happy to help ;)